# Jquery load remote page element according to a string in current page url

Tags: javascript, jquery, load

I'm new in Jquery, I would like to have Jquery code to get the current page url and if the url contains certain string then load remote element.

example:

i have the page urls like this:

```
"http://......./Country/AU/result-search-to-buy"
"http://......./Country/CA/result-search-to-buy"
"http://......./Country/UK/result-search-to-buy"
```

the part "/Country/AU" is what I need to determine which page element I should load in, then if "AU" I load from "/state-loader.html .state-AU", if "CA" I load from "/state-loader.html .state-CA"

I have a builtin module "**{module_pageaddress}**" to get the value of the current page url, I just dont know the Jquery logic to let it work.

I expect something like this:

```
if {module_pageaddress} contains "/Country/AU/" 
$('#MyDiv').load('state-loader.html .state-AU');

if {module_pageaddress} contains "/Country/CA/" 
$('#MyDiv').load('state-loader.html .state-CA');
```

please help and many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>jQuery test page</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function loadContent(elementSelector, sourceURL) {
            $(""+elementSelector+"").load(""+sourceURL+"");
        }
        function stateURL() {
            var startOfResult = '../../state-loader.html #state-';
            var match = (/(?:\/Country\/)(AU|US|CA|UK)(?:\/)/).exec(window.location.pathname);

            if (match) {
                return startOfResult + match[1];
            } else {
                return startOfResult + 'AU';
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="javascript:loadContent('#content', stateURL())">Link 1</a>
<div id="content">content will be loaded here</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the file to load the different content for the states:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
<div id="state-US">Go USA!</div>
<div id="state-CA">Go Canada!</div>
<div id="state-AU">Go Australia!</div>
<div id="state-UK">Go United Kingdom!</div>
</body>
</html>
```

See it work here:

http://www.quirkscode.com/flat/forumPosts/loadElementContents/Country/US/loadElementContents.html

Replace .../US/... with .../AU/..., etc. to see how it behaves.

Original post where I got the ideas/original code:

http://frinity.blogspot.com/2008/06/load-remote-content-into-div-element.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
var countryCode = ... // parse the country code from your module    
$('#yourDiv').load('state-loader.html .state-' + countryCode);
```

See more examples of .load() [here](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

Answer (score 0):

As far as pulling the url path you can do the following

```
var path_raw = document.location.path, 
     path_array = path_raw.split("/");
```

Then, you could do something like this:

```
$.ajax({
     url: "./remote_data.php?country=" + path_array[0] + "&state=" + path_array[1],
     type: "GET",
     dataType: "JSON",
     cache: false,
     success: function(data){
          // update all your elements on the page with the data you just grabbed
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use my one line javascript function for getting an array of the URL segments:  http://joshkoberstein.com/blog/2012/09/get-url-segments-with-javascript

Then, define the variable $countrySegment to be the segment number that the country code is in.

For example:
/segment1/segment2/**CA**/

(country code would be **segment 3**)

Then, check if the 3rd array index is set and if said index is either 'CA' or 'AU'.  If so, proceed with the load, substituting in the country-code segment into the .html filename

```
function getSegments(){
    return location.pathname.split('/').filter(function(e){return e});
}

//set what segment the country code is in
$countrySegment = 3;

//get the segments
$segments = getSegments();

//check if segment is set
//and   if segment is either 'AU' or 'CA'
if(typeof $segments[$countrySegment-1] !==undefined && ($segments[$countrySegment-1] == 'AU' || $segments[$countrySegment-1] == 'CA')){
    $countryCode = $segments[$countrySegment-1];
    $('#target').load('state-loader.html .state-' + $countryCode);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var result= window.location.pathname.match(/\/Country\/([A-Z]+)\//);
if(result){
    $('#MyDiv').load('state-loader.html .state-' + result[1]);
}
```